# Регулярное выражение для поиска и замены переменных в тексте

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Задумал я тут локализацию сайта, но некоторые моменты приходится делать на js.

Вопрос такой:
Необходимо регулярное выражение с помощью которого можно заменить переменные в переменной содержащей html блок, на соответствующие переменные языка.

Имеется переменная содержащая html код который надо вывести на экран. Вот пример.

```
<div class="width-250">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{ev_textone}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{ev_texttwo}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{ev_other}</button>
</div>
```

И вот как видите в коде, есть языковые переменные которые в фигурных скобках.
Есть языковой файл, который подгружен на странице изначально. Задача изменить фигурные скобки с переменными, на соответствующие слова или фразы из языкового массива.

```
var lang = {
    ev_textone: "Это поле не должно быть пустым", 
    ev_other: "Длинна этого поля должна быть от 5 до 30 символов", 
    ev_texttwo: "Максимальная длинна этого поля 255 символов", 
    ev_dateright: "Введите дату и время в формате ДД-ММ-ГГГГ ЧЧ:ММ"
    …
}
```

Данные подгружаются динамически.. после открытия страницы, поэтому я решил сделать вывод необходимого языка таким способом.
Помогите с регулярным выражением или кодом, который поможет мне в этом.

Comment: Где Ваше решение?

Comment: for (var word in lang) {
     m[key]=m[key].split('{'+word+'}').join(lang[word]);
     }
мне кажется очень тяжелым вариантом, т.к. языковой файл у меня достаточно большой.

Comment: Не по теме, конечно, но слово "длина" пишется с одним "н". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let lang = {
  ev_textone: "Это поле не должно быть пустым", 
  ev_other: "Длинна этого поля должна быть от 5 до 30 символов", 
  ev_texttwo: "Максимальная длинна этого поля 255 символов", 
  ev_dateright: "Введите дату и время в формате ДД-ММ-ГГГГ ЧЧ:ММ"
},
  template = `<div class="width-250">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{ev_textone}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{ev_texttwo}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{ev_other}</button>
</div>`;

// Ищем "a-z_"-символы между фигурных скобок
// Если найденная фраза есть в словаре - возвращаем значение, иначе возвращаем найденное
document.body.innerHTML = template.replace(/{\s*([a-z_]+)\s*}/ig, (_, key) => key in lang ? lang[key] : _);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что я хотел.

Comment: @IvanSavin, пожалуйста. Спасибо тут выражаются в репутации и, если решено, принятием ответа (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Обязательно поставлю. Я новый пользователь...